# Dealing with IOS web browsers not caching audio

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, audio, safari

I have a language site that I am working on to teach language. Users can click on objects and hear the audio for what they click on. Many of the people that will be using this are in more remote areas with slower Internet connections. Because of this, I am needing to cache audio before each of the activities is loaded otherwise there is too much of a delay.

Previously, I was having an issue where preloading would not work because iOS devices do not allow audio to load without a click event. I have gotten around this, however, I now have another issue. *iOS/Safari* only allows the most recent audio file to be loaded. Therefore, whenever the user clicks on another audio file (even if it was clicked on previously), it is not cached and the browser has to download it again.

So far I have not found an adequate solution to this. There are many posts from around *2011~2012* that try to deal with this but I have not found a good solution. One solution was to combine all audio clips for activity into a single audio file. That way only one audio file would be loaded into memory for each activity and then you just pick a particular part of the audio file to play. While this may work, it also becomes a nuisance whenever an audio clip needs to be changed, added, or removed.

I need something that works well in a `ReactJS`/`Redux` environment and caches properly on iOS devices.

Is there a 2020 solution that works well?

Comment: Have you tried Cloudflare CDN?

Comment: @Constantin I am not sure that will help too much. Still the problem is with a slow Internet connection and no local caching on the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). It's a low-level API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, including files/blobs. `IndexedDB` API is powerful, but may seem too complicated for simple cases. If you'd prefer a simple API, try libraries such as [`localForage`](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/), [`dexie.js`](https://dexie.org/).

`localForage` is A Polyfill providing a simple name:value syntax for client-side data storage, which uses IndexedDB in the background, but falls back to WebSQL and then localStorage in browsers that don't support IndexedDB.

You can check the browser support for `IndexedDB` here: https://caniuse.com/#search=IndexedDB. It's well supported. Here is a simple example I made to show the concept:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Audio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Audio</h1>

  <div id="container"></div>

  <script src="localForage.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`main.js`

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  localforage.setItem("test", "working");

  // create HTML5 audio player
  function createAudioPlayer(audio) {
    const audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    const audioSrc = document.createElement("source");
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    audioEl.controls = true;
    audioSrc.type = audio.type;
    audioSrc.src = URL.createObjectURL(audio);
    container.append(audioEl);
    audioEl.append(audioSrc);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", e => {
    console.log("page loaded");
    // get the audio from indexedDB
    localforage.getItem("audio").then(audio => {
      // it may be null if it doesn't exist
      if (audio) {
        console.log("audio exist");
        createAudioPlayer(audio);
      } else {
        console.log("audio doesn't exist");
        // fetch local audio file from my disk
        fetch("panumoon_-_sidebyside_2.mp3")
          // convert it to blob
          .then(res => res.blob())
          .then(audio => {
            // save the blob to indexedDB
            localforage
              .setItem("audio", audio)
              // create HTML5 audio player
              .then(audio => createAudioPlayer(audio));
          });
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

`localForage.js` just includes the code from here: https://github.com/localForage/localForage/blob/master/dist/localforage.js

You can check `IndexedDB` in chrome dev tools and you will find our items there:
[image: IndexedDB_Blob]
and if you refresh the page you will still see it there and you will see the audio player created as well. I hope this answered your question.

BTW, older versions of safari IOS didn't support storing `blob` in `IndexedDB` if it's still the case you can store the audio files as `ArrayBuffer` which is very well supported. Here is an example using `ArrayBuffer`:

`main.js`

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  localforage.setItem("test", "working");

  // convert arrayBuffer to Blob
  function arrayBufferToBlob(buffer, type) {
    return new Blob([buffer], { type: type });
  }

  // convert Blob to arrayBuffer
  function blobToArrayBuffer(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", e => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      });
      reader.addEventListener("error", reject);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
  }

  // create HTML5 audio player
  function createAudioPlayer(audio) {
    // if it's a buffer
    if (audio.buffer) {
      // convert it to blob
      audio = arrayBufferToBlob(audio.buffer, audio.type);
    }
    const audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    const audioSrc = document.createElement("source");
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    audioEl.controls = true;
    audioSrc.type = audio.type;
    audioSrc.src = URL.createObjectURL(audio);
    container.append(audioEl);
    audioEl.append(audioSrc);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", e => {
    console.log("page loaded");
    // get the audio from indexedDB
    localforage.getItem("audio").then(audio => {
      // it may be null if it doesn't exist
      if (audio) {
        console.log("audio exist");
        createAudioPlayer(audio);
      } else {
        console.log("audio doesn't exist");
        // fetch local audio file from my disk
        fetch("panumoon_-_sidebyside_2.mp3")
          // convert it to blob
          .then(res => res.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            const type = blob.type;
            blobToArrayBuffer(blob).then(buffer => {
              // save the buffer and type to indexedDB
              // the type is needed to convet the buffer back to blob
              localforage
                .setItem("audio", { buffer, type })
                // create HTML5 audio player
                .then(audio => createAudioPlayer(audio));
            });
          });
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

[image: IndexedDB_ArrayBuffer]

Comment: This code would be much prettier with `async await` instead of promises. Let me know if you want an `async  await` version.

Comment: @kojow7 This article https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-the-service-worker-cache-storage-limit/ mentions that on IOS Safari the `cache` storage has 50mb limit and that `IndexedDB` has at least 500mb limit. I think `IndexedDB` is your best option.

Comment: Do you know if these solutions will work nicely with a ReactJS/Redux framework?

Comment: Of course, they will work. These solutions are just using Web APIs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API  Web APIs are the APIs made available to us by the browser. These APIs are accessible with JavaScript and it doesn't matter if you would use native JavaScript like my example or any JavaScript library like React, Vue, or Angular. BTW, I'm a React developer so let me know if you need help implementing that.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my answer here from the comment.

You can use HTML5 localstorage API to store/cache the audio content. See this article from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

As per the article,

> Make your website more responsive by caching resources—including audio
> and video media—so they aren't reloaded from the web server each time
> a user visits your site.

There is an example to show how to use the storage.

Apple also allows you to use a database if you need so. See this example: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/ASimpleExample/ASimpleExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH4-SW4

Comment: Dear @manishg, the `localStorage` just stores around 5mg. if the downloaded media was upper than this capacity how it will be going on?

Comment: please read the article I shared. It mentions three ways to store data.

Comment: `localStorage` is limited to about 5MB and can contain only strings.

Answer (score 0):

Lets explore some browser storage options

- localStorage is only good for storing short key/val string
- IndexedDB is not ergonomic for it design
- websql is deprecated/removed
- [Native file system](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/) is a good canditate but still experimental behind a flag in chrome
- localForge is a just booiler lib for a key/value storage wrapped around IndexedDB and promises (good but unnecessary)

That leaves us with: [Cache storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

```js
/**
 * Returns the cached url if it exist or fetches it,
 * stores it and returns a blob
 *
 * @param {string|Request} url
 * @returns {Promise<Blob>}
 */
async function cacheFirst (url) {
  const cache = await caches.open('cache')
  const res = await cache.match(file) || await fetch(url).then(res => {
    cache.put(url, res.clone())
    return res
  })
  return res.blob()
}

cacheFirst(url).then(blob => {
  audioElm.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
})
```

Cache storage goes well hand in hand with service worker but can function without it. doe your site needs to be secure, as it's a "power function" and only exist in secure contexts.

Service worker is a grate addition if you want to build PWA (Progressive web app) with offline support, maybe you should consider it. something that can help you on the way is: [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) it can cache stuff on the fly as you need them - like some man in the middle. it also have a cache first strategy.

Then it can be as simple as just writing `<audio src="url">` and let workbox do it thing

Comment: Nice alternative, although bear in mind that iOS doesn't play overly nicely with ServiceWorkers, especially when it comes to using it as a PWA. Not a great experience for the user, so something to bear in mind.

Comment: @TomAnderson What issues does iOS have with ServiceWorkers?